# Ember.js run function after querying model

Tags: ember.js, routes

New to ember, I need to get the data that is about to be used to render a template.

```
var films = [
  {title: 'title 1', director: 'director 1'},
  {title: 'title 2', director: 'director 2'}
]

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('films', function(){
    this.resource('film', {path: ':film_id'})
  })
})

App.FilmsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return films
  }
})

App.FilmController = Ember.ObjectController.extend()

App.FilmRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return films
  }
  // I want to run a function here with the relevant data, eg /films/1
})
```

Seems like the only way I can get the data is by passing a queryParam to the model method on App.FilmRoute.

```
App.FilmRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log(param) // {film_id: "1"}
    return films
  }
})
```

I could then query the model directly. Seems like there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example where the param is used

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/151/edit